# NetBeans 8.2 won't re-install on Mac OSX Sierra 10.13 with JDK 1.8

Tags: macos, netbeans, java-8, installation

I was running NetBeans 8.2. shut it down and moved the project I was working on.  When I tried to start NetBeans again, it failed to start.  After multiple attempts, I finally gave up, deleted it and tried to re-install the same version and now the installer won't even start.  Any suggestions?

NetBeans 8.2 (javaee version, also tried the all version with the same results)

Mac OSX Sierra 10.13.2

JDK 1.8.0_152 (I know about the JDK 1.9 issues)

I won't include the entire dump, but the details of message to "send to Apple" include:

Application Specific Information:
HIToolbox: could not get FSRef for theme file at path '/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Resources/Extras2.rsrc' (errno=2, No such file or directory)
abort() called

However, that file does exist.

-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  5425538 Aug 30 23:23 /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Resources/Extras2.rsrc

I was working fine, moved the project directory I was working in, and things started failing.  I did not install/uninstall/update or modify anything else in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to re-install after a reboot.  No idea what the issue was, but it has been resolved.  Apologies for posting before I tried the newbie fix-all solution.